# PHPにパイプしたメールの日本語文字列の検索ができません。

Tags: php

cPanelのフォワーダーで.phpへメールをパイプし、その本文内の日本語の文字列を検索しようとしていますが、どうしても見つけてくれません。

具体的には、Yahoo!JAPANの路線情報メールを受け取り、その内容の一部を切り取ってデータベースにINSERTする、ということをしようとしています。自分のPC(MAC)から同じメールアドレスにメールを送信した場合は、しっかり"路線名"という文字列を認識し処理をしてくれるのですが、Yahoo!から届くオリジナルメールはスルーされてしまいます。

恐らく、メールやサーバーの文字コードの違いによって認識できていないのだと思われますが、どのような設定、あるいはPHP内での文字コードの変換を行えば、認識できるようになるのでしょうか。

以下、PHPコードと、Yahoo!から届くメール(Header部分含め)を添付いたします。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin' , 'r');
while (!feof($stdin))
{
    $line = trim(fgets($stdin, 4096));
    $wmail .= "\n" . $line;
}
fclose ($stdin);

// 解析
$findme = "路線名";
$start_position = strpos($wmail, $findme);
if ($start_position === false) 
{
    // "路線名"が見つからなかった場合の処理
    exit();
}

// 見つかった場合の処理

?>
```

```
From alerts-error@err.yahoo.co.jp Tue Feb 17 08:01:44 2015
Received: from n30.bulk.ogk.yahoo.co.jp ([124.83.144.223]:46009)
by vps6.globroad.com with smtp (Exim 4.84)
(envelope-from <alerts-error@err.yahoo.co.jp>)
id 1YNUfg-0008Ep-Fe
for xxx@xxx.xxx; Tue, 17 Feb 2015 08:01:44 +0900
Comments: DKIM? See http://antispam.yahoo.co.jp/efforts_dk.html
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mail.yahoo.co.jp; s=bulk201106; t=1424127704; bh=adAS1ct13jodmmWHHOrFRdKNPlPEkpjM09JThfYz3G8=; h=Received:Received:Date:Message-Id:Received:X-yahoo-newman-expires:X-yahoo-newman-id:X-yahoo-newman-property:From:To:Reply-To:Errors-To:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:X-Yahoo-Bounces:X-Yahoo-AlertId:X-Yahoo-Alerts-DLV-Time:X-Yalerts-EncodeEmail; b=WtJA36tgZ3+PrlhrO6SeARq9fnD6IESPnwjrF9KHUf8AhUNhV3GBVwpay9GPko31qgIyKGVvqmrdj/D9XuIVKfDHCg95lmAuVYWLuD32EWY9GEDsgaGXlQFuUeI5Co83pI9UhUcyAZP/NICxnvmfftsxI6IFfL9hLZXO/Hhz898=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws; s=bulk201106; d=mail.yahoo.co.jp;
b=GIOinzlt6c1liFJ2oBM81AZNg2soi8yFPCdQLALGIWR+QmU6n8zsugJprJVMylChX0ug1pxeXRjxJ3Wp/DVgcsoKrueJZTEDIglj9vJoixXhyp0q75hW3Soi5cj5m7hhmTsZweil3FEl2NWKdFC2le1ohnfmmXVr8XH09VVzekw=;
Received: from [124.83.172.207] by n30.bulk.ogk.yahoo.co.jp with NNFMP; 16 Feb 2015 23:01:44 -0000
Received: from [183.79.46.251] by m06.bulk.ogk.yahoo.co.jp with NNFMP; 16 Feb 2015 23:01:44 -0000
Date: 17 Feb 2015 08:01:44 +0900
Message-Id: <54e276d8-000067ff-2fdc29976311e6dd2eaed9de484e011c-7948@dlv136.alerts.kks.yahoo.co.jp>
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by dlv136.alerts.kks.yahoo.co.jp with NNFMP; 16 Feb 2015 23:01:44 -0000
X-yahoo-newman-expires: 1424134812
X-yahoo-newman-id: dlv136.alerts.kks-27117-1424127704-transit-dinfo
X-yahoo-newman-property: alerts
From: "Yahoo! Alerts - Transit"<alerts-transit@mail.yahoo.co.jp>
To: husky_train@location.serverrush.com
Reply-To:"Yahoo! Alerts - Transit"<alerts-transit@mail.yahoo.co.jp>
Errors-To: alerts-error@reply.yahoo.co.jp
Subject: =?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCQW1JcEtcQH4bKEJbGyRCQGlNVSFBRDg7UhsoQl0gGyRCMT8bKEI=?=
=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCOVQ+cEpzGyhCIFlhaG9vIRskQk8pQH4+cEpzGyhC?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-2022-jp"
X-Yahoo-Bounces: 1
X-Yahoo-AlertId: 145639393
X-Yahoo-Alerts-DLV-Time: Tuesday, February 17, 2015, 08:01 AM JST
X-Yalerts-EncodeEmail: iso-2022-jp

Yahoo!路線情報 運行情報
==========================================
xxxさんの登録した路線において、遅延、事故、運転見合わせなどが発生しました。

路線名：総武本線[千葉〜銚子]

07:15頃、総武線(快速)内で線路内点検を行った影響で、千葉〜佐倉駅間の一部列車に遅れが出ています。
（2月17日8時00分現在）

最新の情報はこちらでご確認ください。
http://transit.loco.yahoo.co.jp/traininfo/detail/62/0/

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<お知らせ>
飛行機の運航情報もYahoo!路線情報サイトでご確認いただけます。
国内線も国際線も、日本の航空路線の多くをカバーする主要5空港の情報をお届けします。
フライト情報はこちら（※メール配信機能は現在対応しておりません）
http://yahoo.jp/NR78YH
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
このメールに返信されても、運行情報に関するお問い合わせにはお答えできません。
運行情報メールの配信停止・設定変更: http://transit.loco.yahoo.co.jp/diaedit/mail
ヘルプ・お問い合わせ: http://help.yahoo.co.jp/help/jp/transit/
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copyright (C) 2015 レスキューナウ All rights reserved.
Copyright (C) 2015 Yahoo Japan Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
```

Comment: PHP スクリプトファイルの encoding が `UTF-8` だとして、`fclose()` の後に `$wmail = mb_convert_encoding($wmail, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-2022-JP');` とでもしておけば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 早速ありがとうございます。
mb_convert_encodingでいろいろな組み合わせは試してみたのですが、うまくいきませんでした。念のためいただいたcodeを挿入してもう一度検証してみます。少し時間をください(何せ、Yahoo!からメールが届かないと検証できないので)。

Comment: 余計なことかもしれませんが、`strpos()`  は `true` を返しません(`false` か正の整数を返します)。ですので、`$start_position !== false` とした方が良いでしょう。

Comment: んー。私もstrpos === true が間違っている気がしますね。実際私の個人環境ではその間違いを直せば動きます。あとは入力エンコードは何がくるか不明なのでmb_convert_encodingは、かましたほうがいいです(mb使うならmb_strposの方がいいかもですね)。それもISO-2022-JP固定ではなくContent-Type: text/plain; charset=""を見るかメールパーサーに任せたいところです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
strpos === trueは投稿上の便宜上そう書かせていただきました。実際のコードでは$start_position === falseを使用しています。紛らわしくてすいません(投稿内容を修正します)。

Comment: `strpos()`はマルチバイト対応していません。日本語に使ってはいけません。`mb_strpos()`などマルチバイト対応した関数を、文字エンコーディングを合わせて使う必要があります。

Comment: heliac2001さん、 Norikaz Ishiiさん、 kenjisさん、
ご指摘の通り修正しましたところ、問題は解決いたしました。どうやら、mb_convert_encoding($wmail, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-2022-JP');の'UTF-8'と'ISO-2022-JP'を、逆に記述していたようでした。
助かりました。本当にありがとうございました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @skyElements もしよろしければご自身で回答として投稿していただくと、他の方にも解決策がわかりやすいかと思います。（本当は[回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)までしていただけると有難いのですが、自分の回答は2日経たないと承認できないので・・・）

Comment: @unarist 自分で回答し承認してみました。ご指摘ありがとうございました。stackoverflowもよくわかっていないど素人です。今後ともご指導よろしくお願いいたします(こういう返答もstackoverflow的には必要ないのかもしれませんが・・・)。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントしてくださった方々のおかげで解決いたしましたので、まとめておきます。

```
mb_convert_encoding($wmail, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-2022-JP');
```

を挿入したところ、無事に日本語文字列を検索することができました。メールのencodingと、phpのencodingを統一する必要があったようです。

mb_convert_encodingは、`string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )`
と定義されているように、`mb_convert_encoding(変換する文字列, 変換後のencoding, 変換前のencoding);`の順番です。encodingは両方とも指定する必要があります。

メールのencodingはメールのheader内で確認できますが、転送などを行うと、headerが書き換えられてしまうので要注意です。検証を行う際、メールをtextファイルにして、以下のようにパイプしました。textファイルを保存する際は、encodingをISO-2022-JPなど、オリジナルのencodingにすることに注意してください。

```
$ cat test.txt | parse.php
```

以下、Yahoo!路線情報から受信したメールをforwarderでパイプし、「路線名：」から「現在）」までの文字列をMySQLにINSERTする.phpのコードです。

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin' , 'r');
while (!feof($stdin))
{
    $line = trim(fgets($stdin, 4096));
    $wmail .= "\n" . $line;
}
fclose ($stdin);

$wmail = mb_convert_encoding($wmail, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-2022-JP');

// 解析
$findme = "路線名：";
$start_position = strpos($wmail, $findme);
if ($start_position === false) exit();

$findme = "現在）";
$end_position = strpos($wmail, $findme);
if ($end_position === false) exit();

$end_position = $end_position + 9;

$message = mb_substr($wmail, $start_position, $end_position - $start_position);

// databaseへinsert
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');   
if (!$db) exit();

mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO xxx SET 
message = '%s'",
strip_tags($message));
mysqli_query($db, $sql);

?>
```